# Slick Slider arrows appearing as generic buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js

I'm using Slick and I'm having issues with the dots and buttons. They appear outside the Slick frame as generic buttons. <strike>Accessibility also isn't working.</strike> Edit: Accessibility not working was caused by the slider not having focus.

Here's my Slick code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".single-item").slick({
       accessibility: true,
       arrows: true,
       dots: true
   }); 
});
```

and here's my slider code as well as the JS that generates it:

```
<div class="single-item" id="slideshow">

</div>

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
{
    $("#slideshow").append("<div><img onclick='cover(this)' src='" + images[i] + "'></div>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the `slick-theme.css` file below `slick.css`?

Comment: I asked this so long ago, I can't even remember. I did end up fixing it. I didn't realize I had to style the buttons myself. I also had no idea there was a pre-made theme.

Comment: Hahaha yeah, that happens.